# Is it possible to run tensorflow-gpu inside docker container as non-root user?

Tags: linux, docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I am setting up a docker container to do development with tensorflow-gpu using nvidia GPUs. I am hoping to get all this working as a non-root user inside the container. The container works perfectly as a root user. Any ideas what I need to do to configure the container to work with non-root user?

I have tried to change permissions to user inside the container, but that doesn't seem to work. Also, didn't manage to find any information or related question using google, that would help to solve this issue.

I also tried to compare environment settings between root and the actual user but didn't find clues from there either. Also to note that nvidia-smi call works for both root and non-root user.

I have built the image using this link as a starting point: https://gitlab.com/nvidia/cuda/blob/ubuntu16.04/9.0/runtime/cudnn7/Dockerfile

On top of that, I have installed Python3.5 with necessary packages, including tensorflow-gpu.

Also I have created user into the image as below.

```
ARG USER_NAME
ARG USER_ID 
ARG GROUP_ID

RUN groupadd -g 1004 ${GROUP_ID}
RUN useradd -rml -d /home/${USER_NAME} -s /bin/bash -g ${GROUP_ID} -u ${USER_ID} ${USER_NAME}
```

This way, files created by the container are owned by me in the host, which is desired result. This works fine.

I have tried this setup as a root user and it works.

```
$ sudo docker run -u root -it --runtime=nvidia -v /home/$(whoami):/home/$(whoami) gpu-env bash
$ python3
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

However, this doesn't work.

```
$ sudo docker run -it --runtime=nvidia -v /home/$(whoami):/home/$(whoami) gpu-env bash
$ python3
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```